# In operator returns true in a property not present in an object

Tags: javascript, qml

This is a snippet of code of code in QML Itme which is supposed to be using straight up JavaScript. However I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is going on.

```
    let item =  itemList.get(vmCurrentIndex); // itemList is a ModelList
    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
    console.log(("vmMetadata" in item));
    console.log(("vmIndex" in item));
    console.log(("vmText" in item));
    console.log(("hasMouse" in item));
    console.log(("something" in item));
    console.log(("or" in item));
    console.log(("other" in item));
```

The output of the tests above are:

```
qml: {"vmText":"No protocol","vmIndex":0,"hasMouse":false}
qml: true
qml: true
qml: true
qml: true
qml: true
qml: true
qml: true
```

Which makes no sense. only vmIndex, vmText and hasMouse are in item, everything else should have returned false. How is this possible? If I can't use the in operator how can I test if a key is present in a javascript object?

Comment: When I try your code, I had to change your first line to this: `let item =  {"vmText":"No protocol","vmIndex":0,"hasMouse":false};`. That works for me. I get `true` only for the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th printouts. I'm testing with Qt 5.15.7.

Comment: Why is there `qml: ` in front of all the logs?

Comment: When you console.log, try it without the `JSON.stingify`. The undefined values may have been filtered out.

Comment: Not everything can be converted to JSON which can only represent a very small subset of possible value types in Javascript. Try to do `console.log(item)` and show the output of that.

Comment: Ahh Ok. So whatever is being returned (console.log(item) just returns crap) by the model list seems it can't be properly stringified and it can't be tested via in. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I bypassed the issue. Insetead of checking with in for a property I just checked that the returned value of item["vmMetadata"] is defined.